# $n^{\text{th}}$ derivative of Characteristic function using Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a real valued random variable. If the $n^th$ moment of $X$
exists and is finite (i.e. $E(|X|^n) < \infty$), then  it is n times continuously differentiable and $$\psi_X^{(k)}(0)=i^{(k)}\mathbb{E}X^{(k)}.$$ for all $k=0,1,2,..,n$.
Here my confusion is "where do I use $E(|X|^n) < \infty$" in the following proof.

Suppose for $n=k$ is true. So we need to show for $n=k+1$ is valid.(induction)
Suppose  for  $n=k$ is true. Then $\psi$ is $ k$ times continuously differentiable and 
$$\psi_X^{(k)}(t)=i^{(k)}\mathbb{E}[X^{(k)}e^{itX}],$$ by assumption.

Hence,
$$
\begin{split}
\psi_X^{(k+1)}(t)
   &= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{[\psi _X^{(k)}(t+h)-\psi_X^{(k)}(t)]}{h} \\
   &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{i^{(k)} \mathbb{E}[X^{(k)}e^{i(t+h)X}]-i^{(k)}\mathbb{E}[X^{(k)}e^{itX}]}{h} \\
   &= \lim_{h \to 0} i^{(k)}\mathbb{E}[X^{(k)}e^{itX} (\frac{(e^{ihX}-1)}{h}]\\
   &= i^{(k)}\mathbb{E}[X^{(k)}e^{itX}iX]=i^{(k+1)}\mathbb{E}X^{(k+1)},
\end{split}
$$ from assumption because  $\frac{(e^{ihX}-1)}{h} \rightarrow ix$ as $h\rightarrow 0.$ 
This implies $$\psi_X^{(k+1)}(0)=i^{(k+1)}\mathbb{E}X^{(k+1)},$$  and hence it is valid for $ n=k+1$.

Therefore,  $\psi$ is $ n$ times continuously differentiable and$$\psi_X^{(k)}(0)=i^{(k)}\mathbb{E}X^{(k)}.$$ for all $k=0,1,2,..,n$.

Comment: The fourth equality involves bringing the limit (as $h\to 0$) inside the expectation. It is here that the hypothesis $\Bbb E|X|^{k+1}<\infty$ is used (Dominated Convergence Theorem).

Comment: Ohh I see. Thank you so much. @John